# with open within for loop, TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Python)

Tags: python

I get a str not callable error when opening and reading multiple text files within a loop, starting a the second time/open. Unfortunately I am unable to resolve this problem by myself. Please take a look at my code:

```
for symbol in sorted(list(symbollist.keys())):  
    textfile = symbol+"."+symbollist[symbol]['Country']+".txt"
    textfile = textfile.lower()
    index = symbollist[symbol]['Index']
    country = symbollist[symbol]['Country']
    ticker = symbol
    name = symbollist[symbol]['Name']
    if index not in data:
        data[index] = {}
    if country not in data[index]:
        data[index][country] = {}
    if ticker not in data[index][country]:
        data[index][country][ticker] = {}
    if name not in data[index][country][ticker]:
        data[index][country][ticker][name] = {}
    indexaddress = "d_all_txt\\data\\daily\\us\\nasdaq stocks\\1+2\\" 
    textad = (indexaddress+textfile)
    print(textad)
    with open(textad) as s:
        print("test")   
        next(s)
        for line in s:
```

Output:

```
d_all_txt\data\daily\us\nasdaq stocks\1+2\aaap.us.txt
test
d_all_txt\data\daily\us\nasdaq stocks\1+2\aaba.us.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Historical stock data\import in DB.py", line 46, in <module>
    with open(textad) as s:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have tried opening both files individually/manually by using:

`textad = "d_all_txt\\data\\daily\\us\\nasdaq stocks\\1+2\\aaap.us.txt"`

or

```
textad = "d_all_txt\\data\\daily\\us\\nasdaq stocks\\1+2\\aaba.us.txt"
```

The problem only arises when the code arives at the with open statement for the second time (in the for symbol loop)

Hope someone can help me out with this!

Comment: Somewhere, you have assigned `open` to be a string, but are trying to call it as if it were a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassigned `open` to a string somewhere along the rest of the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you, this is true, open price was variable open, changed it to openp. Impressive. How do I assign this as the right answer?

Comment: @Willem I would generally use `_open` with leading `_` for such cases

Comment: Consider just using an object to bundle the prices together, then you can have `price.open` &c.